# Making tool in ArcGIS from Python script

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, python-script-tool

I was trying to run a tool based on my Python script. So in the script Stak118 is the name of the final output and i got the Stak118 as output in this case. But I would like the output in the tool to get any name based on what user gives in the tool interface. How can I do that?

```
import arcpy
import os
import sys
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
env.workspace = r"H:\Stak1108"
arcpy.env.cellSize = "MINOF"
.... = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
.....
Raster1 = Raster(".....")
Stak118 = Con(Raster1 = 5,1)
Stak118.save(r"H:/Stak1108/Stak118")
´´´
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting confused with your variables, overwriting them and hardcoded strings instead of how you meant to use the string originally stored by the variable. At first the variable outcon0807 gets set to be the input parameter (presumable output file name), but then later on you overwrite it with the output raster itself, and hardcode the output file name. Something similar was happening with all your individual rasters too. I would recommend the following changes, which separate the file names and Raster objects into separate variables:

```
# Import statements and setting the environment
import os
import sys
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
env.workspace = r"H:\Test"
arcpy.env.cellSize = "MINOF"

# Get input parameters - these should all be text strings of the filenames
Raster1filename = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Raster2filename = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Raster3filename = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
Raster4filename = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
OutputFilename = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

# Initial raster processing - create Raster objects from your input raster file names
Raster1 = Raster(Raster1filename)
Raster2 = Raster(Raster2filename)
Raster3 = Raster(Raster3filename)
Raster4 = Raster(Raster4filename)

# Con statement - using Con() statements and Raster objects create a new output Raster object
OutputRaster = Con(Raster4 == 1,Con(Raster2 == 1,Con(Raster3 == 1,Con(Raster1 == 1,3,Con(Raster1 == 2,4,Con(Raster1 == 3,4,Con(Raster1 == 4,3,Con(Raster1 == 5,3,Con(Raster1 == 6,5)))))),Con(Raster3 == 2,Con(Raster1 == 1,3,Con(Raster1 == 2,5,Con(Raster1 == 3,5,Con(Raster1 == 4,3,Con(Raster1 == 5,3,Con(Raster1 == 6,5)))))),Con(Raster3 == 3,Con(Raster1 == 1,4,Con(Raster1 == 2,5,Con(Raster1 == 3,5,Con(Raster1 == 4,4,Con(Raster1 == 5,3,Con(Raster1 == 6,5)))))))))))

# save file - save the output Raster object to a path with the output raster file name
OutputRaster.save(r"H:/Test/" + OutputFilename)
```

When running the script you would then give the input raster file names and "outcon0807" (or whatever you want the output file name to be) as your input parameters.

Comment: Thanks:) But now i get an error like this when i run the code in Pycharm. File "H:/Test/GPAsStack.py", line 19, in <module>
    OutputRaster.save(r"H:/Test/"+OutputFilename)
RuntimeError: ERROR 999998: Unexpected Error."

Comment: Taking a second look, you've got a similar overwriting issue going on with your raster variables. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Also make sure in general you understand the types of your variables (which are strings, which are Raster objects) as well as how variables work.

Comment: I have edited the code but i get a new error.   Raster1 = Raster(cover)
RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset  does not exist or is not supported

Comment: That error means that one way or another your input isn't valid. Check that you are giving a filename to a real raster that exists, and that it is in a format that ArcGIS accepts. For more details see the Raster documentation (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/raster-object.htm)

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs and patience. I have rewritten the code in the question which worked well now. I got the output in the name Stak118 in my working folder.  But still the question of how do I script this so that the name of the output(in this code it is Stak118) is whatever the user puts in for output raster, instead of Stak118?

Comment: Just like you are letting the user input rasters, you need to let them input the output file name rather than hard coding it. Then you use this variable as part of the filename in your final .save() command. Go look at the OutputFilename variable in the code of my answer - this is what you are wanting.

Comment: I did like you said with the saving part but did not work for me. I got the error when i added these two extra lines to the code in the question. RuntimeError: ERROR 999998: Unexpected Error.         
 ```OutputFilename = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)              
Stak123.save(r"H:/Stak1108/"+OutputFilename)´´´

Comment: Use a print statement to check what is getting saved in OutputFilename. If you had a full path (drive, folders, and filename) in there then it would be erroring because it is trying to save the raster to something like "H:/Stak1108/H:/Stak1108/outputraster". If that's the case then just do Stak123.save(OutputFilename) to avoid duplicating the drive and folder information in your path name.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Stack123.save(Outputfilename) worked